# Compare list of values with JSON response using python

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

Having this JSON response in the S3 bucket how can I concatenate all "Text" values, using python, in one string, so later I can iterate and compare this sting with the list. List something like:

```
doc = ["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod",
       "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."]
```

```
[
  {
    "Blocks": [
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ",
        "Page": 1
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Text": "consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod",
        "Page": 5
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Text": "tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
        "Page": 10
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What is the rule that tells you to put `"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "` in front of both `"consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod"` and `"tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."`? What is the rule that tells you *not* to, for example, put `"consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod"` in front of `"tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to traverse the `Blocks` list inside the json response and get `Text` property from each block and append it to a list. Once done, convert that list to a string. [I have used list for performance purpose.]

```
json_response = [
  {
    "Blocks": [
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ",
        "Page": 1
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Text": "consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod",
        "Page": 5
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Text": "tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
        "Page": 10
      }
    ]
  }
]

concat_string_list = []

for block in json_response[0]["Blocks"]:
    concat_string_list .append(block["Text"])

print("".join(concat_string_list))
```

**Output :**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple for each loop iterating over each JSON object and concatenating each "line" to a single string variable should to the trick.

```py
combined_line = ""

for block in data["blocks"]:
    combined_line += block["text"]
```

Comment: better you use for time and space savings

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me how you got that sample result (the same "Text" value is used twice, while the second half is two different "Text" values?)

Here's something similar though.

```
doc = []
json_data = [
  {
    "Blocks": [
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ",
        "Page": 1
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Text": "consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod",
        "Page": 5
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Text": "tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
        "Page": 10
      }
    ]
  }
]
for block in json_data[0]["Blocks"]:
  doc.append(block["Text"])

print(doc)
```